# Objective-C: Proper handling of shared properties between subclassed NSControl and NSActionCell?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscell, nscontrol

One of the things I've always been unsure of is how to properly handle communication between a custom `NSControl` subclass and an `NSCell` subclass. Throughout my introduction to Cocoa, I've seen it mentioned several times how the parent control provides many of the same methods, accessors, and mutators as the child cell's/cells' implementation. For example, the `NSControl` class and `NSCell` class both have `-isEnabled` and `-setEnabled:` in their header files:

**NSControl.h**

```
- (BOOL)isEnabled;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag;
```

**NSCell.h**

```
- (BOOL)isEnabled;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag;
```

I understand that the `NSControl` class provides "cover" methods for *most* of the properties found in `NSCell`. What I'm more interested in knowing is: how are they implemented? Or even better, how should one implement his/her own subclasses' shared properties? Obviously, only Apple's engineers *really* know what's happening on the inside of their frameworks, but I thought maybe somebody could shed some light on the best way to mimic Apple's cover method approach in a nice clean way.

I'm horrible at explaining stuff, so I'll provide an example of what I'm talking about. Say I've subclassed `NSControl` like so:

**BSDToggleSwitch.h**

```
#import "BSDToggleSwitchCell.h"

@interface BSDToggleSwitch : NSControl

@property (nonatomic, strong) BSDToggleSwitchCell *cell;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL sharedProp;

@end
```

And I've subclassed `NSActionCell`:

**BSDToggleSwitchCell.h**

```
#import "BSDToggleSwitch.h"

@interface BSDToggleSwitchCell : NSActionCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) BSDToggleSwitch *controlView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL sharedProp;

@end
```

As you can see, they both share a property called `sharedProp`.

My question is this: What's the standard way to effectively keep the shared property synchronized between the control and the cell? This may seem like a subjective question, and I suppose it is, but I'd like to think that there is a most-of-the-time "best way" to do this.

I've used all sorts of different methods in the past, but I'd like to narrow down the ways in which I handle it, and only use the techniques which provide the best data integrity with the lowest overhead. Should I use bindings? What about implementing custom mutators which call their counterparts' matching method? KVO? Am I a lost cause?

Here are some of the things I've done in the past (some or all of which could be totally whacky or straight-up wrong):

1. **Cocoa Bindings** — I'd just bind the control's property to the cell's property (or vice versa):

   ```
   [self bind:@"sharedProp" toObject:self.cell withKeyPath:@"sharedProp" options:nil];
   ```

   This seems like a pretty good approach, but which object would you bind to/from? I've read all of the KVO/KVC/Bindings documentation, but I've never really picked up on the importance of the binding's directionality when the property should be the same in either case. Is there a general rule?
2. **Send Messages from Mutators** — I'd send the cell a message from the control's mutator:

   ```
   - (void)setSharedProp:(BOOL)sharedProp
   {
       if ( sharedProp == _sharedProp )
           return;

       _sharedProp = sharedProp;

       [self.cell setSharedProp:sharedProp];
   }
   ```

   Then I'd do the same thing in the cell's implementation:

   ```
   - (void)setSharedProp:(BOOL)sharedProp
   {
       if ( sharedProp == _sharedProp )
           return;

       _sharedProp = sharedProp;

       [self.controlView setSharedProp:sharedProp];
   }
   ```

   This also seems fairly reasonable, but it also seems more prone to errors. If one object sends a message to the other without a value check, an infinite loop could happen pretty easily, right? In the examples above, I added checks for this reason, but I'm sure there's a better way.
3. **Observe and Report** — I would observe property changes in each object's implementation:

   ```
   static void * const BSDPropertySyncContext = @"BSDPropertySyncContext";

   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                         ofObject:(id)object 
                           change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                          context:(void *)context
   {
       if ( context == BSDPropertySyncContext && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"sharedProp"] ) {

           BOOL newValue = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];

           if ( newValue != self.sharedProp ) {
               [self setSharedProp:newValue];
           }

       } else {
           [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
       }
   }
   ```

   Once again, this seems doable, but I don't like having to write an `if` statement for every single shared property. Along the lines of observation, I've also sent notifications, but since the control-cell relationship is about as "one-to-one" as one can get (sweet pun intended), that just seems silly.

Again, I know this is a bit subjective, but I'd really appreciate some guidance. I've been learning Cocoa/Objective-C for awhile now, and this has bothered me since the beginning. Knowing how others handle property syncing between controls and cells could really help me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that `NSCell` mostly exists because of performance issues from the NeXT days. There has been a slow migration away from `NSCell`, and you generally shouldn't create new ones unless you need to interact with something that demands them (such as working with an `NSMatrix`, or if you're doing something that looks a lot like an `NSMatrix`). Note the changes to `NSTableView` since 10.7 to downplay cells, and how `NSCollectionViewItem` is a full view *controller*. We now have the processing power to just use views most of the time without needing `NSCell`.

That said, typically the control just forwards messages to the cell. For instance:

```
- (BOOL)sharedProp {
  return self.cell.sharedProp;
}

- (void)setSharedProp:(BOOL)sharedProp {
  [self.cell setSharedProp:sharedProp];
}
```

If KVO is a concern, you can still hook it up with `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` (and its relatives). For instance, you can do something like:

```
- (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSharedProp {
   return [NSSet setWithObject:@"cell.sharedProp"];
}
```

That should let you observe `sharedProp` and be transparently forwarded changes to `cell.sharedProp`.

Comment: Interesting! I *have* noticed the migration away from cells, but I never knew the history behind them. I've always wondered why the `NSCell` class even existed. I've read that they're "views without all of the overhead that comes with a regular view," but since everything has been moving more and more to the GPU, I couldn't imagine why they're still used. Now I know! Thanks for the lesson. I do have one question though. In your example, it looks like the cell is forwarding the message to the control, but you say it's the other way around. Am I just reading this wrong?

Comment: Okay, after reading your example a few more times, I think I understand what you mean. The only place the ivar actually exists is in the control, rather than having one in each of the objects. That makes almost too much sense. That's probably why I didn't think of it. Ha! Thanks, man.

Comment: I wrote it backwards. Typically the cell would have the ivar. One thing to note: a typical use of `NSCell` is in cases where it's reused by multiple views. In those cases, this approach doesn't necessarily make sense. The caller needs to have some awareness of the cell architecture in order to interact correctly.

Comment: I got ya. I've been working on my class, and thanks to your advice, I refactored it completely. Everything's encapsulated in a single NSView subclass now, and if you ask me, it feels a lot cleaner. Regardless of whether it's the "right" way, I certainly like having to only deal with a single view; it's a lot more manageable. Also, thanks for reminding me of the `-keyPathsForValuesAffecting<#Property#>` method. You've really helped a young gun out, and I appreciate it!